# Play logger configuration parameters

Tags: playframework

I would like to pass a parameter from `application.conf` into `logger.xml` where logging is configured.

*application.conf*

```
...
logstash.host = "127.0.0.1"
logstash.port = 1234
...
```

*logger.xml*

```
<appender name="LOGSTASH" class="..">
    <port>${logstash.port}</port>
    <remoteHost>${logstash.host}</remoteHost>
</appender>
```

But the value aren't getting set.

```
|-ERROR in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[LOGSTASH] - 
unknown  host: logstash.host_IS_UNDEFINED
```

What are my options?

I would like not to have also a separate `logger.xml` for every environment, as I already have a separate `application.conf` for each.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's been a long time, but did you find a solution?